# Where do I put the share buttons code? (share42)

Tags: button, share, share-button

I generated the buttons and downloaded a folder that has a .png image a .js file. Where do I put the code and image? I'm only familiar with html and css.

Our website is built on the modx platform. I can edit html and css on the pages.

Answer (score 0):

MODX Revolution (the latest version of MODX) tries not to tell you where to put things like images and css. Traditionally, javascript, css, images, and other front-end static resources go in the "assets" directory.

Edit: I just noticed that your script is share42 and have modified the answer accordingly:

Let's say you unzipped the directory and uploaded it into the assets directory. The file structure in a traditional install would be as follows:

- assets

  - components (used by MODX extras to store their js, css, etc...)
  - *share42*

    - icons.png
    - share42.js
- connectors
- core
- manager

Then, paste the following code in the appropriate place in a MODX template or chunk:

```
<div class="share42init"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="[[++site_url]]assets/share42/share42.js"></script>
```

This should work in a properly-set-up MODX installation, because [[++site_url]] should resolve to the URL of your MODX installation.

Tip: If you are likely to relocate or rename your assets directory, you might want to use `[[++site_url]][[++assets_url]]share42/share42.js` as the script URL isntead.